# CSS progress bar not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a quiz using CSS and HTML in Rails but I can't get the progress bar working. It's using bootstrap but I'm wondering if its the css or bootstrap that's making it not work as intended. When I put my code into jsfiddle it works fine, and displays as circles, but when I try it in rails its just one fixed progress bar.

CSS

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/theme";

/*Progress Rec Quiz styling */

#myQuiz .progress  {
  width: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 40px;
}

#myQuiz .progress div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  transition: background-color 1s;
  left: 40px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="myQuiz">
  <h1>Test your knowledge <span>Loser</span></h1>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="on" ></div>
    <div class="on" ></div>
    <div class="on" ></div>
    <div class="on" ></div>
    <div class="on" ></div>
    <div class="on" ></div>
    <div class="on" ></div>
    <div class="on" ></div>
    <div class="on" ></div>
    <div class="on" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `progress` class appears in Bootstrap, use another class like `custom-progress`.